# Configuring Webpack for Large Websites

Tags: webpack, sass, configuration

This is my folder structure, I need to write webpack configuration for this.

Source

```
src
|--index.pug
|--pages
|--|--temps
|--|--|--_head.pug
|--|--blog.pug
|--style
|--|--temps
|--|--|--_sidebar.scss
|--|--|--_menu.scss
|--|--common.scss
|--|--blog.scss
|--|--index.scss
|--js
|--|--index.js
|--|--blog.js
```

So I want the entry to be from `index.pug` and it should include `index.scss` and `common.scss` other than that each page will include `common.scss` and their particular style from style folder. There are going to be more pug based webpages and it would be nice to dynamically link their specific stylesheet automatically. The build folder structure will be same as the source folder. 
If there's any tutorial that teaches config for large websites please let me know.